# Wordpress Permalinks & Nginx Rewrite Rule Not Working

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, nginx

My Server configuration is:

- Nginx
- php-fpm5

I set up WordPress and it's working fine with custom permalink 'Day and name'. Now I want to set the rewrite rule in the nginx file and it's not working with a clean URL. If I set the permalinks to 'default' the rule works fine.

Also I disable the default WordPress 301 redirection from adding filter for 'redirect_canonical'.

Suppose my post URL is `example.com/2015/03/22/abc-test` and I want to write a rule so that if I enter `example.com/2015/03/22/custom/abc-test` in browser then it should display the content of `example.com/2015/03/22/abc-test`

Nginx Rule:

```
location ~* ^(.*)/custom(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)/custom(.*)$ $1$2 last;
}
```

I need assistance finding out how Nginx rewrite rules work with WordPress permalink.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin in wordpress and write rule which will overwrite nginx rule.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/

When you have wordpress, you have to set permalink to default to work your webserver rule work and if you dont want to do that you have to install above plugin and write rule.

Comment: Suggesting a plugin to do what's possible in the core of the web server quite easily is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Nginx vhost configuration to work with WordPress URL rewriting:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   root "/var/www/staging/example";
   index index.php;
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   }

}
```

There is a complete guide on how to configure Nginx with WordPress [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx).